# Divide the .txt file into array variable

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all, preg-split, file-read

I have a string in text file as

```
haha ;  J1.A1 DUT.A1  DUT.A2 C1.1 C2.1 ,
           F2.1 F4.1 K1.1 , 
           F2.1 F4.1 K1.1 ,
           F2.1 F4.1 K1.1  
aaa;  J1.A1 DUT.A1  DUT.A2 C2.1 C3.1 ,
           F3.1 F5.1 K2.1 , 
           F3.1 F5.1 K2.1 ,
           F3.1 F5.1 K2.1
```

I want store in array like

```
$arr =array("haha J1.A1 DUT.A1 DUT.A2 C1.1 C2.1, F2.1 F4.1 K1.1, F2.1 F4.1 K1.1,F2.1 F4.1 K1.1", "aaa J1.A1 DUT.A1 DUT.A2 C2.1 C3.1, F3.1 F5.1 K2.1, F3.1 F5.1 K2.1, F3.1 F5.1 K2.1");
```

if comma not in the line it goes to next array field

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you just want to remove ; from the input and store it??????

Comment: yes i wants to remove ; but that's not important. i wants to store in array field like above $arr if comma not in the line the array field goes to next array field

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$file = 'my_file.txt';
$text = file_get_contents($file);
$lines = explode(',', $text);
```

$text will contain the whole content of your file.
explode will split $text on each comma. $lines will be an array of strings.

Documentation:
[file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents)
[explode](http://php.net/explode)